# Install Magento 2.2.3 with composer throws

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

I am trying install a clean version of Magento 2.2.3 using composer:

```
 composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

This error is thrown:

```
 Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.3].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

 To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
 You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

What do I need to do to set up my development environment?

Thank you

Comment: just follow http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install-roadmap_cli.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/magento/project-community-edition --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag will tell composer to forget about missing extensions and other PHP requirements and just do what you ask. I am assuming that you are simply creating the project locally but the actual PHP interpreter lives inside your VM, to which these files will be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have **mcrypt**

```
sudo apt-get install php7-mcrypt  
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To check all the installed modules

```
maddy@maddy:~$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you need to enable/install `mcrypt` php extension  follow @inrsaurabh

1. check system requirement meet http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
2. set configuration http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html
3. complete guideline further for installation  http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-install-via-composer-and-command-line-cli/